# What does "blacking brush" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "blacking brush" mean? Wells's short story The Purple Pileus

> It also appears that Clarence was dragged under the sink and his face scrubbed with the **blacking brush**,—he being still resolved to humour the lunatic at any cost,—and that finally, in a somewhat dishevelled, chipped, and discoloured condition, he was assisted to his coat and shown out by the back door, the shopway being barred by Jennie.

Comment: ***blacking*** = *[wax-based] **shoe polish*** or *(cast iron) **stove polish***. Slightly odd, but there it is. They scrubbed his face with a shoe brush rather than a scrubbing brush. Well, I haven't checked the actual source, so feasibly if we're in a "theatre / actor" context from several decades ago, it could be a reference to the makeup brushes used to apply and/or remove ["blackface".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackface)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - we are in 1896 in an English domestic kitchen.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: The full OED's cited use of definition 2b *A preparation for giving a shining black surface to boots and shoes; **a shoe polish*** is dated 1598. The first citation for definition 2c (Founding) *A carbonaceous material such as graphite or powdered coal, used as a facing (facing n. 9) **to improve the finish of castings*** is dated 1813. It could be either type of brush - I mainly chose my interpretation simply because I happen to still have some boot blacking in the cupboard under my sink!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stoves, especially cast iron ones, are usually black and so would grates have been at the time Wells was writing. In order to keep them in condition you would apply stove black or stove blacking. Naturally the brush used would be a blacking brush. By the sound of it they were in the kitchen or scullery (since it had a sink, not a basin, and would have been near the back door) which would have had a range for cooking on which would also have been black.

Comment: Is it tar or paint of some sort? Why would anyone need to cover their stoves with it?

Comment: If you do a search for stove black paint and then get the images you will see lots of pictures of the product. It is used to keep the stove looking smart just as you paint anything really.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Hot cast iron gets unsightly surface rust patches *very* quickly in contact with any moisture. I use my stove for heating saucepans and a kettle, so need to scrub and re-black the top surface fairly regularly. Historically that was the norm before gas and then electric kitchen appliances came about - stoves were often much more complex, incorporating ovens and dedicated hotplates. Search "cast iron range".

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev: Stove blacking is basically just finely-powdered graphite (from charcoal, coal, etc.)  made into a paste with a bit of water. Unlike *boot* blacking, it doesn't normally include wax (because that would stink when it burned off).